# Create calculated fields in crosstab

Tags: tableau-api, crosstab

I have a crosstab between supplier and order acceptance status, containing maxvalue of a number.

I need to create a formula like : 
`IF ACCEPTED > MISSING THEN "GOOD" ELSE "BAD"`

Can you help with the syntax?

[image]

This is what I get using formula suggested and this is what I should get

```
ORDER   |   ACCEP   |   MISSING |   SHOULDBE    |   NOW     |       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
61010   |   6       |   0       |   GOOD        |   GOOD    |   FORMULAOK   
61011   |   3       |   12      |   BAD         |   BAD     |   FORMULAOK   
63239   |   9       |   11      |   BAD         |   BAD     |   FORMULAOK   
66749   |   0       |           |   BAD         |   GOOD    |   FORMULAnotOK    
76824   |   2       |   1       |   GOOD        |   BAD     |   FORMULAnotOK
```

Comment: You have a column in your data called NOW. But you haven't told us what that formula is so we can't give you feedback on what to change. Please edit your question to include the code you are currently using. Also, the values for Order 66749 need the formula to account for null values (hint: use the isnull() function).

Answer (score 0):

Use a **SUM()** and **INT()** function to do Conditional Checks ,convert Boolean as Numbers and add the numbers to get total counts. Then its just a comparison.

```
IF SUM(INT([ACCEPTANCESTATUS]="ACCEPTED")) > SUM(INT([ACCEPTANCESTATUS]="MISSING")) 
   THEN "GOOD" ELSE "BAD" END
```

Comment: thanks it still doesn't work .. see above table with examples ( apologies im struggling in formatting text and dont get how to upload files ... )

Answer (score 0):

You're data is already pivoted, you can just write a calculated field exactly has you framed your pseudo code:

```
IF SUM([ACCEP]) > SUM([MISSING]=) 
THEN "GOOD" 
ELSE "BAD" 
END
```

You can remove the sum elements if you want the value calculated for every row (and not aggregated).

Comment: i need to compute a Max function on a Revision field , not a sum. and I can't get how to define in the formula which is the field to aggregate ..

Comment: Did you try switching the formula from SUM to MAX?  Can you explain more about what you mean by "which is the field to aggregate?"